# Manipulate android apps that don't work with Talkback

Tags: android, talkback

I recently used Talk back on an Android device. Some apps don't work well with the Talk Back screen reader because the it's not developed according to the accessibility API. Is there any way that I can access the UI of these apps (from OS level) and manipulate them to be compatible with Talk back?

Answer (score 1):

No. Such change should be made in code. There is no way to modify it from OS level.

Those changes have to be made in XML or Java. User cannot access these values from system layer (security policy). You can refer to: [Android Developer guidlines](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/apps.html#label-ui) for accesibility. Without proper 'contentDescription' set TalkBack is unable to retrive any information about some views: images, imagebuttons etc.

Comment: Do you have any links to provide details on why it can't be modified from the OS level?

Comment: Those changes have to be made in XML or Java. User cannot access these values from system layer (security policy). You can refer to: [Android Developer guidlines for accesibility](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/apps.html#label-ui). Without proper 'contentDescription' set TalkBack is unable to retrive any information about some views: images, imagebuttons etc.

Comment: You should edit your answer to include your comment.